# login script not working

Tags: php, mysql, authentication

I am trying to check the login, then trying to echo basic user info. Thanks in advance for everyones help. Any suggestions on why I'm unable to echo row data based on a specific logged in user?

```
     <?php
        <?php
    session_start();
    // dBase file
    include "config.php";
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
    if (isset($_GET["op"] ) && $_GET["op"] == "login")  
  {
  if (!$_GET["username"] || !$_GET["password"])
    {
    die("You need to provide a username and password.");
    }

  // Create query
  $q = "SELECT * FROM `users` "
    ."WHERE `username`='".$_GET["username"]."' "
    ."AND `password`=PASSWORD('".$_GET["password"]."') "
    ."LIMIT 1";
  // Run query
  $r = mysql_query($q);
  $row = mysql_assoc_array($r);
  $count = mysql_num_rows($r);
  if ($obj = mysql_fetch_object($r) && $count == 1)
    {
    // Login good, create session variables
    $_SESSION["id"] = $row['id'] = $obj->id;
    $_SESSION["user"] = $row['username'] = $obj->username;
    $_SESSION["time"] = time();
    // Redirect to member page
    Header("Location: welcome.php");
    }

  else
    {
    // Login not successful
    die("Sorry, could not log you in. Wrong login information.");
    header("Location: login2.php");
    }
}
     {
//If all went right the Web form appears and users can log in
  echo "<form action=\"?op=login\" method=\"GET\">";
  echo "Username: <input name=\"username\" name=\"username\" size=\"32\"><br />";
  echo "Password: <input type=\"password\" name=\"password\" size=\"32\"><br />";
  echo "<input type=\"submit\" value=\"Login\">";
  echo "</form>";
  }
    ?>
```

Comment: Get rid of the `@` as they hide the errors you need for troubleshooting. Also ,what errors do you get? What have you done to debug this?

Comment: Please describe the exact problem you are having,.

Comment: http://localhost/APP/login/login2.php?username=admin&password=sniper

Comment: @John- got rid of @. The form is passing the $_GET variables, but its not redirecting.

Comment: Are you getting the `Sorry, could not log you in. Wrong login information.` message?

Comment: I'm not able to log a user in, $_GET variables get passed, but does not do anything else

Comment: Add `ini_set('display_errors', 1)` to the top of the page.

Comment: added, not getting any error though

Comment: Maybe something bad with my $sql call?

Comment: what is the output of your code,. is it display any error or show the message and die in else condition

Comment: Remove that localhost link in your comment above. Not only does it not work for anyone except you, it has your username and password in it!

Comment: you have assign  $_SESSION["user"] = $row['username']; there should be $_SESSION["user"] = $obj->username;

Comment: @innovativekundan Do you mean this?

Comment: // Create query
  $q = "SELECT * FROM `users` "
   ."WHERE `username`='".$_GET["username"]."' "
   ."AND `password`=PASSWORD('".$_GET["password"]."') "
   ."LIMIT 1";
  // Run query
  $r = mysql_query($q);
  $row = mysql_fetch_array($r);

  if ($obj = mysql_fetch_object($r) )
   {
   // Login good, create session variables
 $_SESSION["id"] = $row['username'];
 $_SESSION["id"] = $obj->id;
   $_SESSION["user"] = $row['username'];
 $_SESSION["user"] = $obj->username;
   $_SESSION["time"] = time();
   // Redirect to member page
   Header("Location: welcome.php");
   }

Comment: @MichaelRushton any ideas? My login isn't redirecting. It just stays on the same page

Answer (score 0):

You're using `mysql_fetch_object` so you need to do:

```
$_SESSION["user"] = $obj->username;
```

Rather than:

```
$_SESSION["user"] = $row['username'];
```

Comment: Changed it to you're suggestion, and no, im not even getting that message, I know Im typing it in right.